# What does the PROXIMITY parameter describe (Incident API)

Tags: here-api

What exactly does the PROXIMITY parameter describe, and why do ORIGIN and TO always have the same PROXIMITY?

Please see the below json snippet taken from the HERE Incident API for an example -

**EDIT:**
My question is not specific to the json example below but a more general question regarding the meaning of the PROXIMITY parameter.

For instance, "midway between" is pretty self explanatory. What does it mean for a traffic incident to be "at" two points or "past" two points?

In addition, for all the data I have looked at ORIGIN:PROXIMITY:DESCRIPTION is **always** the same as TO:PROXIMITY:DESCRIPTION. Why?

````
{
    "INTERSECTION": {
        "ORIGIN": {
            "ID": "",
            "STREET1": {
                "ADDRESS1": "Pletschenau"
            },
            "STREET2": {
                "ADDRESS1": "Schillerweg"
            },
            "COUNTY": "Calw",
            "STATE": "",
            "PROXIMITY": {
                "ID": "MID",
                "DESCRIPTION": "midway between"
            }
        },
        "TO": {
            "ID": "",
            "STREET1": {
                "ADDRESS1": "Pletschenau"
            },
            "STREET2": {
                "ADDRESS1": "Birkenweg"
            },
            "COUNTY": "Calw",
            "STATE": "",
            "PROXIMITY": {
                "ID": "MID",
                "DESCRIPTION": "midway between"
            }
        }
    },
    "GEOLOC": {
        "ORIGIN": {
            "LATITUDE": 48.73873,
            "LONGITUDE": 8.73767
        },
        "TO": [{
            "LATITUDE": 48.74108,
            "LONGITUDE": 8.73581
        }]
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

We expecting that your use case does match with the example as follows https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/traffic-incidents-via-proximity

This example retrieves traffic incident information related to a specific area of Berlin, as defined by a radius of 15km around a specific point (the prox parameter)

The start(origin) and to(destination) both represents same waypoint here. this explains why these two are not different. In case your API call is different, please share the rest API call.

Comment: No the api call I used is - https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.json?apiKey=[MY_KEY]&bbox=48.176045,8.324032;49.288299,10.18072. So I did not use the prox parameter you linked to. Please see my edit above to the question for more clarification. @HERE Developer Support